# Get user list of users inside an Azure AD instance from postman

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I would like to get the list of users inside a Azure AD instance using postman. If any one has done this, please let me know the URL and the credential details for the same.

Comment: If you have any more concern feel free to share.

Comment: Thank you for the cool answer. I also need to get users from a group that is inside my AD instance, any idea ?

Comment: Yeah you can. But You haven't accept this answer

Comment: Here you can get Member of a group `https://graph.windows.net/YourTenant.onmicrosoft.com/groups/YourGroupObjectId?api-version=1.6`

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply, but I am getting the response as "code": "Authentication_ExpiredToken" for this URL," and token is not expired, it works for other requests
Is there anything more that needs to be configured ?

Comment: I will accept it surely, :)
I am passing the token and same token works for other requests
Any more configuration needs to be done ?

Comment: Kidding man, you token resource is not correct it should be : `resource:https://graph.windows.net` also request endpoint should be `https://login.microsoftonline.com/YourTenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/token`

Comment: The actual URL should be https://graph.windows.net/tenant_id/groups/object_id/members?api-version=1.6, but for this, the request while retrieving the token the resource field should contain resource : https://graph.windows.net
But the token received with this change does not work for my previous get user list (first question)

Comment: I don't understand you are doing something otherwise many me please show me the sample as the comment already become large . I need Your request sample. User List also work , may be you are trying in wrong way

Comment: Is there any way by which we can get the group user list by passing the group name to the URL instead of the group object_id ?

Comment: I don't think its possible without group Id

Answer (score 2):

***Request URL:***

```
https://graph.windows.net/YourTenant.onmicrosoft.com/users?api-version=1.6
```

You can also try with Tenant ID:

```
https://graph.windows.net/3deed68b_Tenant_ID_ef7cfbe/users?api-version=1.6
```

You can also apply custom query `SELECT`

```
https://graph.windows.net/YourTenant.onmicrosoft.com/users?api-version=1.6&$select=id,mail,userType,userPrincipalName
```

You can also apply custom query `SELECT` and `$filter`

```
https://graph.windows.net/YourTenant.onmicrosoft.com/users?api-version=1.6&$select=id,mail,userType,userPrincipalName&$filter=userPrincipalName eq 'admin@ericmlab.onmicrosoft.com'
```

***Credentials Details:***

You need following request permission credentials to set:

***Steps To Set:***

***Step:1***

[image]

***Step:2***

[image]

***Step:3***

After adding permission you have to `Grant Consent` for that like below:

[image]

Now you are ready to call it from post man.

***Postman Example:***

*1. Only User Example*

[image]

*2. User With Custom Query*

[image]

**Note:**

[image]

For more details you could refer below resources

1. [Azure Ad graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#basic-operations-on-users--)
2. [Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Comment: Hi I have also specified the URL how you can get group member list. Let's try and let me know if you have any more concern.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Graph API and the url goes as follows,

https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users?api-version[&$filter]

Follow the documentation from [`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#GetUsers)